# Creating a single select dropdown menu from a JSON file

Tags: json, angularjs, select, drop-down-menu, angularjs-ng-repeat

So I have this json file I need to process:
http://pastebin.com/6aYkTjsw

I'm trying to make 1 single select dropdown menu for each entry in links array for each version. So basically 2 entries should be added to the select dropdown menu for each version (one for windows and one for linux).

However, i'm failing as its making a select element for each version. I can't add another ng-repeat within the select statement so I am a bit confused on how I can accomplish this. I've tinkered around with ng-options and other things but couldn't manage to get it to work.

Here is the current implementation:
http://plnkr.co/edit/TenmOPpXef85KAowXbTx?p=preview

Code:
index.html

```
    <!-- Algorithmic Trading © -->
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Algorithmic Trading - Revitpo Inc</title>

      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="appDownload">
     <div ng-controller="VersionController">
     <!-- Drop Down Menu -->
     <div ng-repeat="x in deployments">
     <select>
     <option ng-repeat="y in x.links" value="{{y.link}}">{{x.short_descr}} ({{y.os}})</option>
     </select>
     </div>
     </div>

    <tt>Copyright © 2015. Revitpo Inc. All Rights Reserved.</tt>
    </body>
    </html>
```

app.js

```
    var app = angular.module("appDownload", []);

    app.controller("VersionController", function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get('http://algorithmictrading.azurewebsites.net/json/versions.json').
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.deployments = data;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue. (Actually icebox from freenode irc  in #angularjs solved it for me).

This is what I ended up using:

index.html

```
<!-- Algorithmic Trading © -->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Algorithmic Trading - Revitpo Inc</title>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="appDownload">
 <div ng-controller="VersionController">
 <!-- Drop Down Menu -->
 <select>
 <option ng-repeat="deployment in deployments" value="{{deployment.link}}">{{deployment.short_descr}} ({{deployment.os}})</option>
 </select>
 </div>

<tt>Copyright © 2015. Revitpo Inc. All Rights Reserved.</tt>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module("appDownload", []);

app.controller("VersionController", function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.deployments = [];

  //Retrieve all build versions
  $http.get('json/versions.json').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    //Push required fields onto array
    data.forEach(function(item1) {
      item1.links.forEach(function(item2) {
        $scope.deployments.push({
          short_descr: item1.short_descr,
          link: item2.link,
          os: item2.os
        });
      });
    })
  });

});
```